# IL Emit base class name is the same as inherited class; protobuffer does not accept cyclic inheritance

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, cil, reflection.emit, emit

I have emitted code that returns an object of a type  passed in, where propertychange notification is wrapped into virtual properties, with modification tracking for the client. This new type will be shared between the client and the server (serialized using protobuf.net). I'm limited to not using third-party libraries, other than the use of protobuf.net.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to serialize a list of new objects (for example, TypeA) using protobuffer, I run into "Unexpected sub-type: TypeA", and when I try to add the SubType as a model for the protobuffer using RuntimeTypeModel, I run into a "Cyclic inheritance is not allowed", which protobuffer does not accept at this time, AFAIK.

I'm new to Reflection.Emit - is there a way to type the new class emitted different than the type I'm emitting, at least in name? I may be able to overcome the cyclic inheritance restriction in this case. I'd like to avoid creating/copying new objects.

For instance, emit a new object as:

```
NewTypeA
-base TypeA
```

instead of:

```
TypeA
-base TypeA
-sub-type TypeA
```

IL Emitter:

```
usage: Type aType = CreateProxy(TypeA);
       Activator.CreateInstance(aType);

public static Type CreateProxy(Type type)
{
    var assmName = new AssemblyName("DynamicProxyAssembly");
    ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    mb = _ab.DefineDynamicModule(assmName.Name);

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = mb.DefineType(type.Namespace + "." + type.Name + "__proxy", TypeAttributes.Public, type);
    typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged));

    FieldBuilder eventField = CreatePropertyChangedEvent(typeBuilder);

    MethodBuilder raisePropertyChanged = CreateRaisePropertyChanged(typeBuilder, eventField);

    MethodInfo isModifiedSetMethod = type.GetProperty("Modified").SetMethod;

    foreach property in type where virtual, wrap method with propertychangednotification...

    Type ret = typeBuilder.CreateType(); // this returns TypeA__proxy derived from itself (base=TypeA__proxy).
}
```

Comment: Some code would help considerably. It's entirely unclear what you mean with "emitting different than the type you're emitting". Derived classes can always be cast back to their base classes, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you very much for taking a look. I've attached a sample of the code - please let me know if you'd like more detail where I supplied pseudo-code to wrap the virtual properties with propertychanged and modified.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've emitted a new type entirely and receive the same errors from Protobuffer. It looks like it's the way the list serialization is done in protobuffer and I'll need to look at the way the list is serialized. Thanks again for taking a look. I'll post the answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it was the RuntimeTypeModel used when serializing through protobuffer. There was nothing wrong with sub-classing the emitted type with the derived type.

I needed to add the type of the instance instead of TypeA:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(TypeA), true).AddSubType(555, typeAinstance.GetType());
```

...before I had:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(TypeA), true).AddSubType(555, TypeA);
```

which, of course, returned a cyclic error.

I hope this helps someone in the future.